# How to a denormalize repeating mysql data?

Tags: mysql, sql, export-to-csv, denormalization

Hi I need to do some denormalizing on a MySQL table with repeating data.

My "Publications" table is currently in this format:

```
Publications Source Table   

|  title                   |       author
--------------------------------------------
|  my paper                |       michael
|  my paper                |       bill
|  my paper                |       jill
|  other paper             |       tom
|  other paper             |       amy
|  third paper             |       ben
|  third paper             |       sophie
```

I need to change it to this format:

```
Publications Destination Table

|  title                   |    author   |  author2   |  author 3
|-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  my paper                |    michael  |  bill      |  jill
|  other paper             |    tom      |  amy       |
|  third paper             |    ben      |  sophie    |
```

Now, just for your information I need to do this so I can eventually get a CSV file so the data can be exported from an old system into a new system that requires a CSV file in this format.

Also there are many other fields in the table and about 60,000 rows in the source table, but only about 15,000 unique titles.  In the source table there is one row per author.  In the destination, **title** will be  a unique identifier. I need one row per unique publication title. Also I can calculate in advance what the most number of authors is on any one publication, if that makes the problem easier.

How can I do this in MySQL?  Thanks

Comment: Your google search string is `mysql pivot query`

Comment: The first table design above is better than the one you want to create, but still needs work. I would have the publications table just contain the title and any other information that a publication could only have one value for. Then a separate table for each piece of info that a publication could have multiple values for.

Comment: Please not that the format I'm trying to get to is simply a format for which someone else has already written an import program. The data will end up in a highly normalized enterprise database system, BUT the vendor has given us the option to import data into it using this specific CSV format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually want to alter the structure of the table, and instead just want to get the data out so you can import it into a new system, you could try the GROUP_CONCAT() function in mysql:

`SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(author SEPARATOR "|") AS authors FROM publications GROUP BY title;`

I've used the pipe as a separator as there's a good chance your titles will contain commas. If you want this to end up as a csv file, you could do a find-and-replace on the pipe character to turn it into whatever it needs to be (e.g., `", "`).

Comment: I think the OP is much better served by a *query* that produces the right output than by restructuring the table to produce the right output.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction I would still have to add the header columns "author1, author2 ... author13", and combine to text files, but that not difficult.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is that you actually normalize the table instead of adding new columns for supplemental authors. So your new table structure would look something like this:

```
Publications Source Table   

|  title_id         |       title
--------------------------------------------
|  1                |       my paper
|  2                |       other paper
|  3                |       third paper


|  title_id      |       author
--------------------------------------------
|  1             |       michael
|  1             |       bill
|  1             |       jill
|  2             |       tom
|  2             |       amy
|  3             |       ben
|  3             |       sophie
```

Comment: Why would you recommend that since I need the data in that format so it can be exported from an old system into a new system that requires a CSV file in this format.

Comment: If this other system is "new" do you have any control over it? Can you change its requirements? Or advocate for change? What I proposed is more in line with standard database design practice. With your design it would be much more difficult to write queries against the tables in the new system if the csv reflects the new table structure. And my design is more flexible in terms of the number of authors per title. Your design will create lots of empty author fields when a title has fewer than the maximum which I'm assuming is frequent.

Comment: Adding new surrogate id numbers has *nothing* to do with normalization.

Comment: The id numbers have to do with creating a schema which will "Free the database of modification anomalies" as discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and many other places. Repeating the titles over and over throughout a table is how to denormalize a table.

Comment: This is not a debate about normalization, I just need to get a csv file that is in the target format, because, someone else has already written an import program that uses that format.  The data will eventually end up in a highly normalized database, but I have 2 options: 1: Enter 15000 records manually, provide the vendor with the CSV file and they will import it for me.